# Can we use rem unit beyond font-size?

Tags: css

I know rem unit is well accepted among browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=rem when it comes to font-size property. However, i'm wondering about other properties like padding, margin or even something less common like outline and letter-spacing. Is it safe to use rem on that?

Comment: Depends on your definition of “safe”! What kind of support do you need?

Comment: Meaning browser? My minimum requirement is IE9+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Rem units can be used anywhere where a regular length value is allowed. The exception is that IE9–10 have a bug where a rem value can't be used in the font shorthand, but it can be used in the individual font-size property.

Comment: Is this exclusive to IE10 or does it affect IE9 too?

Comment: I think it affects IE9 too, but I need to double check. Yeah, it is an issue with IE9 too http://jsfiddle.net/caTFp/